# Can someone make one se'udah for both a bris and a wedding on the same day?

Tags: wedding, brit-milah, sheva-brachos

A woman marries a divorced man (well...until today.) The man wants to make a brit for his son (from his previous wife) on the same day as the brit. To save money, he wants to make a combination se'udah for both events.

Any halachic problems with doing this, or does each occasion require its own se'udah? If they can do one, what would be the order of the brachot at the end - Brit benching or sheva brachot first?

Comment: There are multiple Halachic problems with such a wedding. A more realistic hypothetical would be a man marrying a second wife on the day of his son-from-another-wife's bris. Is there a reason you specifically wanted the mother to be making the Seuda? Also, is the triple bris really part of the question? Do you expect a different answer if it was one or two?

Comment: As I recall the Rambam, they could not have gotten married before the end of the pregnancy or even before the baby is weaned. IIRC they have to wait three months to ensure she is not pregnant and then wait until the baby has been weaned (2 years). I do not have it with me so cannot give the quote.

Comment: Where is the proof a woman can accept a get when she is pregnant.

Comment: @preferred I meant that the case of the question can be whether she is a widow or a divorcee. In either case it is talking about remarrying while pregnant. The halacha in the Rambam places no restrictions on when the man gives her the get and the takana forbidding giving it to her against her will also does not say that it cannot be given while she is pregnant (if she is willing). The limitations on her remarrying also do not differentiate between a widow or divorcee. Those limitations were not affected by the takana

Comment: @sabbahillel Perhaps you misunderstand me. Considering a woman is not allowed to marry after a get if she is pregnant for quite some time, maybe they made restrictions on giving her a get during this time. I would like to know the proof that they didnt since this would have been the best method to enforce it.

Comment: @preferred When the RAMBAM discusses the matter and states how long she must wait, he does not mention anything about not allowing the husband to give a get. As a secondary point, the halachos of waiting before remarriage are given for both a widow and a divorcee without any difference between them. That would be the point at which such a difference as you suggest would have to be stated. No such difference is stated at all. There might be such a suggestion in modern times, but I have not seen such a thing enforced.